# How can a bitwise operator be used to read a file?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, bit-manipulation, ifstream

I'm trying to read from a .dat file using the following code:

```
ifstream input_file; 
double x;
while (input_file >> x) {...}
```

I don't understand how this actually works though - `input_file >> x` seems like it's using the right bit-shift operator.  In what way does that actually read the file?

Comment: Where did you get this code?

Comment: I assume this is C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: The actual meaning of an operator isn't fixed in C++, but depends on its context. Classes can change the meaning of an operator using operator overloading. For an example of this taken to an extreme see [Boost Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html)